# Hitting API and navigating to home or login screen without distrubing splash screen animation?

Tags: flutter, api, animation, splash-screen, flutter-getx

I have an animate splash screen. Also, I am hitting an API before navigating to the Home or Login screen.
The problem is when I call other functions in the splash screen. It disturbs the animation of the splash screen.
I am calling the `getPreferenceData()` function in the `animationInitialization()` function because of that the animation is sluttering.
Now, what should I do? Is it ok to call a function in the `main()`? OR
is there any way to make it smooth within the `SplashScreenViewModel` class?

I Get API Response within 3 to 5 sec.

Splash Screen:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GetBuilder<SplashScreenViewModel>(
        init: SplashScreenViewModel(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/logo.png',
                    width: controller.animation.value * 200,
                    height: controller.animation.value * 200,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Splash Screen View Model:

```
class SplashScreenViewModel extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    animationInitilization();
    super.onInit();
  }

  animationInitilization() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    animation.addListener(() => update());
    animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
    getPreferenceData();
  }

  Future<void> getPreferenceData() async {
    print("prefs");
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    kLanguageCode = prefs.getString('languageCode') ?? "nl";
    kLoginStatus = prefs.getBool('loginStatus') ?? false;
    kTaskerId = prefs.getString('taskerId');
    await getMenuList();
    await getLanguageFile().then(
      (value) => getFlagList().then(
        (value) => navigateToHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> navigateToHomePage() async {
    print("navi");
    kLoginStatus
        ? Get.to(
            () => CommonBottomNavigationBar(
              enableTitle: false,
              itemList: const [
                TaskListPage(),
                TaskListPage(),
                TaskListPage(),
                TaskListPage(),
              ],
              onWillPop: () async {
                return false;
              },
            ),
            preventDuplicates: false,
            transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
          )
        : Get.to(
            () => CommonBottomNavigationBar(
              enableTitle: false,
              itemList: const [
                LoginScreen(),
                NotificationPage(),
                LoginScreen(),
                NotificationPage(),
              ].obs,
              onWillPop: () async {
                return false;
              },
            ),
            preventDuplicates: false,
            transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
          );
  }
}
```

API Hitting Function :

```
Future<void> getLanguageFile() async {
  late Language language;
  Response response = await GetConnect().post(
      baseUrl + usersPathApi + userLanguage, {},
      headers: {"accept-language": kLanguageCode});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    language = Language.fromJson(response.body);
    kLanguageInfo = language.languages;

    try {
      kLanguageList.update((val) {
        kLanguageList.value = language.data.first;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      kLanguageList.value = language.data.first;
    }
    kLanguageList.refresh();
  }
}

Future<void> getFlagList() async {
  List<LanguageInfo> languageInfo = [];
  // Storing the language code and flag in the language_dropdown_model_class
  for (LanguageElement languageList in kLanguageInfo) {
    languageInfo.add(
      LanguageInfo(
        country: languageList.code.toUpperCase(),
        image: languageList.flag,
      ),
    );
  }
  kLanguageDropDown.obs.update((val) {
    kLanguageDropDown.value = languageInfo;
  });
}

Future<void> getMenuList() async {
  Response response = await GetConnect().post(
    baseUrl + usersPathApi + menuItem,
    {},
    headers: {
      'accept-language': kLanguageCode,
    },
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    try {
      kMenuItemsList.obs.update((val) {
        kMenuItemsList.value = Menu.fromJson(response.body).data;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      kMenuItemsList.value = Menu.fromJson(response.body).data;
    }
    kMenuItemsList.refresh();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to run the animation to the end no matter what?

Comment: yes, until i get response from the api i want to run the splash screen smoothly.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the code that is calling the API and doing some processing? It looks like the processing is taking too much CPU.

Comment: I have added the API hitting funtion in mt question. Have a look. Sorry, I can't share the API.

Comment: From the time spent calling the API of 3 to 5 seconds, it looks like the data being returned is huge. That being said the CPU is getting overloaded with work and it competes with the animation. I think if you split the processing into chunks and process each chunk individually in a matter of 10-20 milliseconds it would keep the animation running smoothly.

Comment: As you said, the data i get is big.I have already seperated the functions as much as possible. Is there any other way or is it ok to call the functions in `main()` function

Comment: First you should figure out what's exactly lagging the animation. Check if just calling the APIs without doing anything with the response the lag happens. If so, I'd recommend you paginate the calls to the API and get 100 items per call. If not, the processing of the response is the culprit. Then, you'd need to split the response into chunks and process the chunks one by one in an [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) or even in the main isolate with [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)

Comment: Also, check if in release mode it happens with `flutter run --release`. The thing is that in debug mode there are a lot of asserts being made that don't exist in release mode and this makes the code slower. You can try the `flutter run --profile` to check where the sluggish is too.

Comment: I have checked it. API is the problem. Without the API function the splash screen is smooth.